# Creating a loop to reiterate a section of the code and then print multiple lines to text file

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, text-files

So the code below is code used in a course I'm taking. The code asks a user to enter a true or false question ( TF), or multiple choice question ( MC), followed by question value. The code then outputs the question and answer in a text file. While the code works. It only asks for one question, my first issue, and also needs to print those questions to a text file, second issue.

I've also turned in the assignment already, we didn't necessarily need to modify the code, but I do want to understand how to tackle the issue. My first thought was to look at functions int loadArray and addQuestion and perhaps tweak those but I'm not sure.  Apologies for any formatting errors, I did my best to make it browser friendly.

**Thinking like a programmer is not my strong suit -face palm-**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <fstream>

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Question // super class

{

public:

    string getQuestion()//gets the question

    {

        return question;

    }

    virtual int getValue() //gets the point value of the question

    {

    return value;

    }

    virtual string getQuestionType()// gets the type of question

    {

        return questiontype;

    }

    virtual void setQuestion(string answer, int value)

    {

    }

    virtual void setNewQuestion(string answer, int value)

    {

    }

    virtual void printOptions()

    {

    }

    virtual string getAnswer()

    {

        return answer;

    }

private:

    string question,  answer;

    int value;

    string questiontype;

};

//The class for True/False Questions

class QuestionTF: public Question

{

public:

    void setQuestion(string theQuestion, int pointValue)

    {

        string theAnswer;

        questiontype = "TF";

        question = theQuestion;

        value = pointValue;

        options = "true or false";

        //get the answer from the file

        getline(cin,theAnswer);

        answer = theAnswer;

    }

    void setNewQuestion(string theQuestion, int pointValue)

    {
        string theAnswer;

        questiontype = "TF";

        question = theQuestion;

        value = pointValue;

        options = "true or false";

        //get the answer from user

        cout<<"Enter answer true or false\n";

        getline(cin,theAnswer);

        answer = theAnswer;
    }

    int getValue() //gets the point value of the question

    {

        return value;

    }

    string getQuestionType()// gets the type of question

    {

        return questiontype;

    }

    void printOptions()//prints the options for that question

    {

        cout<<question<<endl;

        cout<<answer<<endl;

    }

    string getAnswer()//outputs the answer for that question

    {

        return answer;

    }

private:

    string question, questiontype;

    string answer;

    string options;

    int value;

};

//The class for Multiple Choice Questions

class QuestionMC: public Question  
{

public:

    void setQuestion(string theQuestion, int pointValue)

    {

        string line;

        questiontype = "MC";

        //get the number of choices from the file

        getline(cin,line);

        numberOfOptions = atoi(line.c_str());

        question = theQuestion;

        value = pointValue;

        //get the individual choice lines and load to options array

        for (int count = 0; count<numberOfOptions;count++){

            getline(cin,line);

            options[count] = line;

        }

        //get the answer from the file and load into answer

        getline(cin, line);

        answer = line;

    }

    void setNewQuestion(string theQuestion, int pointValue)

    {

        string line;

        questiontype = "MC";

        //get the number of choices from the user

        cout<<"Enter the number of choices:  ";

        getline(cin,line);

        numberOfOptions = atoi(line.c_str());

        question = theQuestion;

        value = pointValue;

        //get the individual choice lines and load to options array

        for (int count = 0; count<numberOfOptions;count++){

            cout<<"\nEnter option:  " << count + 1 << endl;

            getline(cin,line);

            options[count] = line;

        }

        //get the answer from the user and load into answer

        cout<<"\nEnter Answer:  ";

        getline(cin, line);

        answer = line;

    }

    void printOptions()// prints the questions, options, and answer

    {

        char first = 'A';

        cout<<question<<endl;

        for(int count = 0; count<numberOfOptions;count++){

            cout<<first++ <<".  "<<options[count]<<"\n";
        }

        cout<< answer << "\n";
    }

    int getValue() //gets the point value of the question

    {
        return value;

    }

    string getQuestionType()// gets the type of question

    {

        return questiontype;

    }

    string getAnswer()// prints the answer

    {

        return answer;

    }

private:

    int numberOfOptions;

    string question, answer;

    string options[6];

    string questiontype;

    int value;

};

//  Function prototypes for the functions supporting the main program functionality

int  loadArray(Question *myQuestions[]);

int addQuestion(Question *myQuestions[], int numquestions);

void printQuizQuestions(Question *myQuestions[], int numquestions);

void writeExamQuestionFile(Question *myQuestions[], int numquestions);

int main() {

    Question *myQuestions[10];

    int numquestions;

//opening the testbank file and processing as a question of each type

try {

ifstream infile("testbank2.txt");

streambuf *cinbuf = cin.rdbuf();  //save old buf

cin.rdbuf(infile.rdbuf());       //redirect std::cin to infile.txt!

string line, theQuestion, theAnswer;

numquestions = loadArray(myQuestions);

cin.rdbuf(cinbuf);   //reset to standard input again

}

catch (exception& e) {

cout << "Hey man, you tried to get away with dividing by zero on line 204, so I jumped to the catch part with the exceptions!!!";

cout <<  "Whoa buddy!!!  Everything stops here!!!  Something went wrong with reading the infile like: " << e.what() << ".  Check the contents of testbank2.txt";

}

numquestions = addQuestion(myQuestions, numquestions);

printQuizQuestions(myQuestions,  numquestions);

cout<<"Write to exam File";

try {

      // code here

ofstream outfile("examoutputfile.txt");

streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //save old buf

cout.rdbuf(outfile.rdbuf());     //redirect std::cout to out.txt!

writeExamQuestionFile(myQuestions, numquestions);

cout.rdbuf(coutbuf); 

//reset to standard output again

cout<<"Exam File Written.\n"<<"\n";

}

catch (exception& e) {

  cout << "Exception occurred";

}

getchar();

return 0;

}

// Function to load the array of Questions from the input file

int loadArray(Question *myQuestions[])

{

string line;

string questiontype, theQuestion;

int numquestions, questionvalue;

//get the number of questions from the first line in the file

    getline(cin,line);

    numquestions = atoi(line.c_str());

    for(int count = 0; count<numquestions;count++){

        getline(cin,line);

        int npos = line.size();

        int prev_pos = 0;

        int pos = 0;

        while( line[pos]!=' ')

            pos++;

      questiontype = line.substr(prev_pos, pos-prev_pos);

       prev_pos = ++pos;

     questionvalue = atoi(line.substr(prev_pos, npos-prev_pos).c_str()); 

       //process a true/false question

        if (questiontype == "TF")

        {

            myQuestions[count] = new QuestionTF;

            getline(cin,theQuestion);

            myQuestions[count]->setQuestion(theQuestion,questionvalue);

        }

        //process a multiple choice 

        if (questiontype =="MC")

        {

            myQuestions[count] =new QuestionMC;

            getline(cin,theQuestion);

            myQuestions[count]->setQuestion(theQuestion,questionvalue);

        }

    }

    return numquestions;

}

int addQuestion(Question *myQuestions[], int numquestions)

{

 cout<<" Welcome to A+ Exam Builder" << endl;

 cout<< "=======================" << endl;
 cout<< "=======================" << endl;

        int questionvalue;

        int count=numquestions;

        string theQuestion,line, questiontype;

        cout<<"Enter the Question type: 'TF' for true or flase, 'MC' for multiple choice and then value (1-100)\n";

        getline(cin,line);

        int npos = line.size();

        int prev_pos = 0;

        int pos = 0;

        while( line[pos]!=' ')

            pos++;

        questiontype = line.substr(prev_pos, pos-prev_pos);

        prev_pos = ++pos;

        questionvalue = atoi(line.substr(prev_pos, npos-prev_pos).c_str()); 

        if (questiontype == "TF")

        {

            myQuestions[count] = new QuestionTF;

            cout<<" \nEnter the Question: ";

            getline(cin,theQuestion);

            myQuestions[count]->setNewQuestion(theQuestion,questionvalue);

        }

        if (questiontype =="MC")

        {

            myQuestions[count] =new QuestionMC;

            cout<<"=======================";
            cout<<" \nEnter the Question: ";

            getline(cin,theQuestion);

            myQuestions[count]->setNewQuestion(theQuestion,questionvalue);

        }

        return ++numquestions;

}

void printQuizQuestions(Question *myQuestions[], int numquestions)

{
    for(int count = 0; count<numquestions;count++)

    {

        myQuestions[count]->printOptions();

        cout<<"\n";

    }

}

void writeExamQuestionFile(Question *myQuestions[], int numquestions)

{

int count;

string qtype;

cout<<numquestions<<"\n";

for (count=0;count<numquestions;count++){

    qtype=myQuestions[count]->getQuestionType();

    cout<<qtype<<" "<<myQuestions[count]->getValue()<<"\n";

    myQuestions[count]->printOptions();

}

}
```

Comment: Far too much code here. There's about 300 lines of the stuff even after correcting for the double spacing. The first step in solving any problem is to isolate the problem so you have a smaller surface area to investigate. Give [mre] a read for some tips on that. I also recommend reading Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Another thing you can do to help yourself is to take advantage of whatever debugging utility came with your development environment. With a debugger you can run the program at a rate you can keep up with so you can see what the program really does as it does it. The debugger will also show you the contents of the variables in use so you can catch if a variable is set to the wrong value. Very handy. Figuring out Turbo Debugger early is probably the only reason I had free time back when I was learning programming in school.

Comment: Thank you, this is great help